# Diagrams used to model the architecture and functionality of a website

Tags: web-development, documentation, uml

I am attempting to understand what UML models/diagrams can be used to communicate a websites architecture.

The model or models' purpose is to communicate the architecture and functionality of a website to technical people (other software developers and engineers).

Website Features:
- The website is a recipe search engine
- Server side code is Python. Client side uses HTML, CSS, JQuery and AJAX.
- The website will have a Web Crawler/Indexer
- Infinite Scrolling is utilised when viewing search results so I will need to model asynchronous requests (both GET and POST).

The diagrams I am tending towards are Component Diagram (to communicate the architecture) and Sequence Diagram (to communicate the functionality of a HTTP request).

What diagrams have you used in the past to communicate the architecture and functionality of a website to technical people?

Comment: You might want to add an Interaction diagram and data modelling...

Comment: As you mentioned the diagrams should communicate functionality, I'd definitely add Case diagrams to those mentioned by @LoBS. It's the best place to start and may show up features that have been either missed out, or are redundant.

Comment: [Nice article about UML Diagrams](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/31863)

Comment: take pen, paper and draw some free form boxes and arrows. Thats the best kind of diagrams in the world. UML was created for snake oil salespeople to impress suit-and-tie guys in leather chairs, and using it for such a simple thing as crawler with web face - is just an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that UML models and diagrams only serve to communicate the architecture to technical people, you might probably be wrong, since **architecture has to be communicated to a lot of other people**, especially to those sitting in management with black suits and wanting to have some good reasons why money/time/resource has to be spent in order to realize a specific architecture.

That's also one of the reasons, why UML provides such a large set of different diagrams, which simply aim at **different stakeholders with different (technical) knowledge**.

Another reason for using different diagrams is simply the complexity of a project. In general you can have static (concerning structures), dynamic (concerning runtime behavior) and allocation (concerning environment mapping) views on a software project. Including them in one diagram would result in a big mess, so you split them up to just have a part of the overall-complexity in one diagram.

Relating to your approach, the component diagram is a static view on the system and the sequence diagram is a dynamic view on the system, so this is quite a good start for documenting architecture.

It's also clear that you don't have the time/money to document each and every possible view/diagram for your system. The consequence is that you have to choose the most important ones, but between which criteria? One the one hand, you have to **determine the main kind of complexity** in your system. Since web projects have mainly runtime behavior, you would concentrate on the dynamic view of your system. On the other hand, **quality attributes** like performance or availability play an important role in determining your efforts in documenting, since they are cross-cutting your whole project and therefore cost a lot if you missjudge them.

And as I mentioned above, if black-suited guys hear the cost-bell ringing, they want to get thorough justification and what would in this case be better than having some diagrams in your pocket describing the most complex system-parts with stakeholder-adjusted complexity?

In order to get a general understanding on architecture documentation, I strongly recommend the paper by Philippe Kruchten [Architectural Blueprints - The 4+1 View Model](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf) After you have read it, it might be much easier for you to determine which models/diagrams you need.